# Wrong src-uri in rails app using font-awesome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, font-awesome

I have configured a Rails application to be hosted using nginx and Phusion Passenger. When I access the site at `http://hostname/vns/` everything loads properly but I see 404 errors for the font-files being requested:

```
open() "/sites/apps/assets/fontawesome-webfont-f1c2889911d212e1403b68eabc1a3a5
6.svg" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

The application is found in /sites/ruby-apps/application/ and /sites/apps/vns is a symlink to /sites/ruby-apps/application/public/

When I look at the CSS generated by `rake assets:precompile` I see that there are two application.css files in public/assets.

application.css has the right path listed in src:url ("/vns/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot")
application-md5fingerprint.css does not have the proper path ("/assets/fontawesome-webfont-009f6d1f667cc42c25e712ab3429cbc7.eot")

Based on what I've tried to figure out so far I should be using RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT but so far it hasn't seem to have any affect when I include it in my production.rb file like so:

```
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/vns"
```

The relevant sections of my configuration:

```
http {
...
  passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.10;
  passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby;
  passenger_max_pool_size 10;
  passenger_pool_idle_time 0;

  passenger_log_level 0;
  passenger_debug_log_file /var/log/nginx/passenger.log;
...
}

server {
...
  passenger_base_uri /vns;

  location /vns {
    passenger_enabled on;
  }
...
}
```

If anyone can help point me in the right direction with regards to solving this I would be much appreciative.

Comment: I solved this but I'm not allowed to answer my own question yet so I will do that once I am able to. Answer has been edited into the question for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this after many hours of trying to resolve it and solved my own issue about five minutes later. Including the answer here for others that might find this:

It looks like I was using ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] improperly.

When I moved it to my asset precompile line like so:

```
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/vns' rake assets:precompile
```

everything came out as expected. I'm not familiar enough with Rails to know what I was doing wrong or if there is a better way to solve this issue but this is fixes it for me.